# how to override default action bar with custom layout actionbar

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

I try to get rid of default action bar by load a custom action bar. But then, it become like this :

[image]

FYI : this project is including navigation drawer sidebar. I am not really sure if the `gray block` thingy come from navigation drawer.

Comment: so you want to add custom actionbar instead of activity action bar

Comment: yes @Allu load from layout resource

Answer (score 0):

try like this it may helpful

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle("Project1");
        actionBar.setDisplayOptions(actionBar.getDisplayOptions()
                | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActionBar()
                .getThemedContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        final View customActionBarView = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.custom_actionbar, null);
        actionBar.setCustomView(customActionBarView);
```

here **custom_actionbar**  is the xml file to add items in actionbar(like text,images and all)